# Checking if value exists in array

Tags: c#, arrays, blazor

Checking if "Item1" exists in ArrayOfItems.

For example, if I check simple condition like @if("Item1 == "Item1"), it returns true and displays dropdown items. But ArrayOfItems.Contains("Item1") always returns false, even though ArrayOfItems has "Item1" and "Item2"

```
      @if (ArrayOfItems.Contains("Item1")) // this always returns false
      {
        <li class="dropdown-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" data-id=3>
            <label for="cb4"> Item Height/label>
        </li>

         <li class="dropdown-item">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb5" data-id=4>
         <label for="cb5"> Item Width </label>
         </li>
     }

    @code {        
        public string ItemName{ get; set; }
        List<string> ArrayOfItems= new List<string>();     

                private void HandleNameSent(string ItemName)
        {            
            JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "ItemName", ItemName);
            ArrayOfItems.Add(ItemName);
            JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "ArrayOfItems", ArrayOfItems);  // returns an array with two values "Item1" and "Item2"        
        }

     
   }
```

May I know what could be the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially when the page was rendered, `ArrayOfItems` was empty.

Whenever data gets updated after the page has already initialized, you need to call `StateHasChanged()` to re-render with the updated data.

```
private void HandleNameSent(string ItemName)
{            
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "ItemName", ItemName);
    ArrayOfItems.Add(ItemName);
    StateHasChanged();
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "ArrayOfItems", ArrayOfItems);       
}
```